# Tomcat and Apache comparison

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

What interests me are the similarities and the differences between tomcat and apache.
When would one be used and when the other?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat is a Java servlet container.
Apache2 is a web server.

You can't run Java servlets in Apache. You wouldn't run anything else than a Java servlet in Tomcat.

You use Tomcat (or other Java servlet container - jboss, glassfish, etc) when you want to run a Java web application. You use Apache2 (or other web servers) when you want to run something else (static web, php, perl, python, etc).

Google Fu:

- http://www.coderanch.com/t/85639/Tomcat/Difference-Tomcat-Apache-Web-Server
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34959/how-are-apache-http-server-and-apache-tomcat-related-if-at-all
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632/difference-between-the-apache-http-server-and-apache-tomcat
- https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+tomcat+and+apache